# Advice needed with back button on the device

Tags: android

I am working on an android app,coming to the point, one activity in the app has two edit text fields, the first field gets active that is gets enabled when the activity is started, and it is only after the first text field is filled, the second field becomes active. This part work correctly.
Now what the problem is when the user fills the second text field and presses the back button on the device, the second text field should get saved and should become inactive, also when the user again goes to the same activity, the second text field should remain inactive,and should get active that is editable only after the user double taps the second edit text field.
I know that database would be needed for saving the data entered in the second field,but even if that is used how should I resolve the problem above, I'd really appreciate your help.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

over ride this function  `onBackPressed()`. In this function, write your code to "save" the text box contents and `onResume()`, you can re-load the text with the saved value.

Answer (score 0):

override

```
 onPause()
```

and

```
onResume()
```

to do your task.

Answer (score 0):

You could aslo try `startActivityForResult()`